# Does the ccgrg package still work on mathematica 12?

Tags: packages, compatibility

I have a number of notebooks written for whatever the current version was of Mathematica in 2019 (not 1919 as I had earlier) and using the `ccgrg` package for general relativity. They now no longer work. There is no error, but the key functions such as `tRicciR[a,b]` that should give something like

```
tRicciR[1, 1]

(* (2 α λ + x^2 β^2 λ^2 + y^2 β^2 λ^2 + 4 z^2 β^2 λ^2 - *********** *)
```

but just return `tRicciR[a,b]` rather than evaluating the function. Is this a known problem? And If there is no way to get `ccgrg` to run in 12, is there a way to resurrect the 2019 version of Mathematica? I've lost a lot of work if it is a dead package

Here is the outpout that fails at the first ccgrg call:

[image]

Comment: Did Mathematica of 1919 work with a slide rule?

Comment: Ooops. I am stil stuck in the last century it seems. Edited.

Comment: Crossposted [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2481999).

Comment: Link related to the package: https://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/8848/

Comment: there are alternatives if you want to code curvature tensors. a package is not required. there are good, thorough answers on this site as well.

Comment: Have you tried contacting the developer of this package? That seems to be a good avenue that has solve similar problems with outdated packages not working in current versions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We talked to Andrzej Woszczyna who is part of the ccgrg team. He was still using an old version of Mathematica and did not know of the problem.  It turns out that Mathematica broke several things when upgrading beyond Mathematica 12.2. These can be fixed by including the lines

```
If[$VersionNumber >= 12.2,
   SetOptions[ValueQ, Method -> "Legacy"];
   SetOptions[Solve, Assumptions -> {}]];
```

before the `` Needs["ccgrg`"] `` command.

Comment: I think it's better to accept this answer instead. (It's perfectly OK to accept your own answer. )

Answer (score 2):

It worked for me. See the following, please:

[image: pic]

Comment: Thanks.  I wonder if I've screwed up. I did re-download and reinstall the version from the Mathematica site, but still not doing what I expect.

Comment: @mikestone what I did is the following: unzipped the file, and then opened the `assistant.nb` and followed precisely the instruction that was given there, i.e copy and paste `ccgrg.m` on the right path. if you think this answer is helpful, consider accepting it by clicking on the checkmark sign

Comment: @ckr  I got back to this, and ccopied your file exactly. When I ran it it aborted at the first ccgrg command. I've added rthe output to my original question.